# Calculating occurrences of values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've this sample table in Excel

```
code type
alfa-1  a
alfa-2  d
beta-1  d
beta-2  c
beta-3  a
alfa-1  b
beta-2  d
```

and I need to calculate, for each "`type`" (i.e., a, b, c and d ...), whether a value is associated with a code.

My desired result would look like this:

```
 code   a   b   c   d
alfa-1  1   1   0   0
alfa-2  0   0   0   1
beta-1  0   0   0   1
beta-2  0   0   1   1
beta-3  1   0   0   0
```

I am aware that I can achieve this result using a pivot table, but I would like to obtain the same result without using a pivot table and instead using some formulas.

Comment: Have you tried `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: so simple using like BruceWayne
 said countifs to find the values-=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$8,$H2,$G$2:$G$8,I$1)-h2 for code and I1 for type, then for code a simple unique and for type transpose + unique

Answer (score 3):

Doing this by formula could look like:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(u_c,SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A8)),u_t,TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B8))),VSTACK(HSTACK("code",u_t),HSTACK(u_c,COUNTIFS(A2:A8,u_c,B2:B8,u_t))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> function as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,B2:B8,
     b,A2:A8,
     ua,TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(a))),
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     c,MMULT(--(TOROW(b)=ub),--(a=ua)),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("Code",ub),
     VSTACK(ua,c)))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(
    d, B3:C9,
    c, TAKE(d, , 1),
    t, DROP(d, , 1),
    suc, SORT(UNIQUE(c)),
    tut, TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(t))),
    HSTACK(
        VSTACK("Code", suc),
        VSTACK(tut, MAP(suc & tut, LAMBDA(m, --ISNUMBER(XMATCH(m, c & t)))))
    )
)
```

[image]